# Raspberry pi 4 autostart app on selected screen

Tags: boot, pi-4

I'm trying to run 2 apps automatically after boot on raspberry pi 4. I already able to make them run after boot by using autorun file but i have no idea how to assign them to run on the selected screen(i.e: screen 1 open terminal and screen 2 open browser).
Is there a way to run them on the selected screen? Thx for the help.

Comment: If you are attempting to use .bashrc you have been seriously mislead

Comment: Shoul i use rc.local then?

Comment: No! You need to take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works.
[How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should use **systemd** Unit files. Please have a look at [Questions tagged (systemd-startup)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd-startup)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single virtual display across several screens (so you can drag windows from one screen to the other), the position of an app window is defined by virtual screen coordinates. Some apps support specifying the window position at startup, with `--geometry` or a similar command line parameter. AFAIK `firefox` supports `-width` and `-height`. Check the manual for the programs that you use.

Alternatively, you can move/resize almost any window using `xdotool`:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name firefox windowmove    0 1080 # skip the first FullHD screen
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name firefox windowsize 1920 1080 # Fullscreen on second FullHD screen
```

If you have separate Xorg displays on separate screens, then you can specify the screen using the `DISPLAY` variable, e.g.

```
DISPLAY=:1 firefox
```